# How to update pandas cell values based on starts with

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe as a:

```
a = {'TXI':  ['TXI|GS|-4.08|ABCD', 'TXI|TX|0', 'TXI|SP|7.06|ABCD']}
a = pd.DataFrame (a, columns = ['TXI'])
```

I am trying to drop the last 5 characters based on starts with to have a result like b:

```
b = {'TXI':  ['TXI|GS|-4.08', 'TXI|TX|0', 'TXI|SP|7.06']}
b = pd.DataFrame (b, columns = ['TXI'])
```

The code I tried below doesn't update the data frame. Where is wrong?

```
for i in a.TXI:
    if not i.startswith('TXI|TX'):
        i = i[:-5]
```

Comment: just replace with this code a.TXI = i[:-5],  inside if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with assign and apply:

```
a = a.assign(TXI = lambda x: x['TXI'].apply(lambda s: s[:-5] if s.startswith('TXI|TX') else s ))
```

the result would be:

```
                 TXI
0  TXI|GS|-4.08|ABCD
1                TXI
2   TXI|SP|7.06|ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `where` function
[image]

```
a.TXI.where(a.TXI.str.startswith('TXI|TX'), a.TXI.str[:-5])

0    TXI|GS|-4.08
1        TXI|TX|0
2     TXI|SP|7.06
```